# NextJS 13 Server Components with Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, react-server-components

Good day guys,

I haven't really seen much coverage on Firebase and using NextJS 13+ to get your firebase firestore data in your app with server components. So using the fetch api etc so that its rendered on the server.

Is this possible with firebase at all or are we for now stuck with "use client" components to do so?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the same thing. Some articles point out that the Admin SDK is made for the server, but others specify you do not need the Admin SDK to use Firestore on the server.

But whenever I try to initialize Firestore, it gives the error:
`Server Error
Error: Service firestore is not available`

Comment: You definitely need to use Admin SDK to work with Firestore on the server. That is literally the point of that lib.

Answer (score 0):

This might not specifically answer but I'm experiencing the same thing trying to work out how to approach things (added complication that I'm in a create-t3-app world so tRPC to contend with) but I'm currently working through this guide where it leverages both the admin SDK and client side

https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-nextjs#0

and supporting code

https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-web/tree/master/nextjs-end

Comment: Here's another one worth researching @Demonix https://next-firebase-auth-edge-docs.vercel.app/